# I have a mlx90614 sensor and I am interfacing it with Raspberry Pi 3 B+ it gives output -273

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

It works fine when I run it for the first time but once I run my LCD code then I run my MLX90614 code, it gives an output -273 after restart it will work fine(using 2 different codes for mlx90614 and LCD).

```
import smbus
 
class MLX90614():
 
    MLX90614_RAWIR1=0x04
    MLX90614_RAWIR2=0x05
    MLX90614_TA=0x06
    MLX90614_TOBJ1=0x07
    MLX90614_TOBJ2=0x08
 
    MLX90614_TOMAX=0x20
    MLX90614_TOMIN=0x21
    MLX90614_PWMCTRL=0x22
    MLX90614_TARANGE=0x23
    MLX90614_EMISS=0x24
    MLX90614_CONFIG=0x25
    MLX90614_ADDR=0x0E
    MLX90614_ID1=0x3C
    MLX90614_ID2=0x3D
    MLX90614_ID3=0x3E
    MLX90614_ID4=0x3F
 
    def __init__(self, address=0x5a, bus_num=1):
        self.bus_num = bus_num
        self.address = address
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(bus=bus_num)
 
    def read_reg(self, reg_addr):
        return self.bus.read_word_data(self.address, reg_addr)
 
    def data_to_temp(self, data):
        temp = (data*0.02) - 273.15
        return temp
 
    def get_amb_temp(self):
        data = self.read_reg(self.MLX90614_TA)
        return self.data_to_temp(data)
 
    def get_obj_temp(self):
        data = self.read_reg(self.MLX90614_TOBJ1)
        return self.data_to_temp(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sensor = MLX90614()

    print(sensor.get_obj_temp())
```

[image]

Comment: When all the addresses show like that you've either got SDA & SCL swapped, you've got a broken I2C device or something is holding SCL low.

Comment: @Dougie It's probably something holding SDA low (rather than SCL).  SDA being pulled low is how a device signals to i2cdetect that it is present on the bus.